# Using list_filter with Intermediary Models

Tags: python, django, django-admin

We have three models, `Artist`:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    family_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    given_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

`Group`:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, through='Membership')
```

and `Membership`:

```
class Membership(models.Model)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    joined = models.DateField()
```

`Membership` is an intermediary model connecting `Artist` and `Group` with some extra data (date joined, etc.) I was asked to see if one could filter artists by what group they're in but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a m2m between artist and group using through=Membership, you can set up a filter directly on group without going through membership.  Can't remember if the syntax is

```
list_filter = ['group']
```

or

```
list_filter = ['group_set']
```

or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried both of those and got errors saying that the field `group` or `group_set` didn't exist.